# What is the POM file to be used when manually installing a JAR file to maven local repository using eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, maven, repository, local

When packaging a project as a jar file, maven includes the pom file of the project inside the jar.
I am using Eclipse Indigo and have installed the m2e.
To install a JAR artifact I go to Eclipse-> Import -> Maven -> Install package to local repo...
Then I click on the browse button and select the JAR I want to install
I also provide: groupid, artifactid, version, classifier, etc

Regarding the POM file, eclipse provides me with three options:

1. To click on a browse button and select a POM file (which I can obtain by extracting it from the JAR), or
2. To check a checkbox requesting the creation of a POM file, or
3. To leave blank the "selection of a POM" and to uncheck the "create POM".

Considering my JAR file includes a POM inside which contains the JAR's dependencies, what is the correct way of installing the JAR into the local repository?

Answer (score 0):

You should extract the pom file and add it to the option, it is strange to have to pom file inside the jar this is not the normal case.

Normally you would deploy the file to your local repo and remote repo using the install plugin in the project which compiles that jar from source. The install plugin will copy/upload the pom file in addition to the jar but not within it.